# Кеширование картинок с удаленного сервера

Tags: php, кэширование

У нас на сайте выводятся картинки с удаленного сервера, т.к. пусть к картинкам задан с другого ftp, каждая картинка весит около 5мб.

Пользователю нужны именно эти размеры, что бы можно было детально рассмотреть картинку продукта.

Какие варианты оптимизации есть? Возможно из как-то кешировать? Держать из на сервере с сайтом очень ресурсазатратно. Картинок всего на 500ГБ.

Какие варианты решения, оптимизации есть?

Comment: хранить картинки на отдельном http сервере и отдавать клиентам сразу с него

Comment: а какая разница ftp или http?

Comment: заголовки кеширующие поставить, хотя может и ftp кешируется. Можно еще заресайзить картинки. Вообще в чем проблема-то?

Answer (score 1):

Поставить Nginx
Использовать ETAG
Использовать Last Modified

Если ftp сервер где то с плохим интернетом или далеко от основного сервера
Сделать проксирование с кэшом на основном сайт и можно добавить ресайзинг на потерю качество или заранее обжать

А можно сделать 1 картинку хорошо обжатую которую видно на сайте, а вторую при нажатии на картинку что бы увидеть оригинал